# How to translate datetime in uint to python?

Tags: python, string, uint

I am migrating some data from an old system, and an object has an attribute in the date format, but the value of the attr is a uint:

```
| HW buy date  | date   | NULL   3983 |  4 |   10019 | NULL | **1639004400**
```

The new system uses date in a string format. How can I retrieve a date from this value in Python?

Comment: `1639004400` is epoch time stamp, look into how you convert that and you got yourself a date. Edit: I see the play of words here, not that kind of date. :)

Comment: What does the uint value mean (probably the epoch time)?

Comment: Converting gives me: GMT: Wednesday 8. December 2021 23:00:00